# Number guessing game, unable to take the next guess

Tags: python, random

Here is the concept of my game, the computer randomly generates a number from 1-100 and the player has to guess that number. If the number they guess is higher or lower the computer tells them so.

I added some code to make sure that the guess that the user enters is a number, but for some reason, it only works for their first guess.

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = input("Guess the number")

while guess.isnumeric() == True:

    if x > int(guess):
        print("Too low, guess again")
        guess = input("Guess the number")

    if x < int(guess):
        print("Too high, guess again")
        guess = input("Guess the number")

    if x == int(guess):
        print ("That is correct!")
        break

if guess.isnumeric() == False:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        guess = input("Guess the number")
```

I don't really know how to else to explain it. But for example, if I guess the number 20 as my first guess, it would output too high or too low depending on the randomly generated number, but after that, if I input a bunch of random letters it would give me an error that the guess could not be compared to the randomly generated number.

Comment: Please do include the *full traceback* of the error in your question; you are, I'm guessing, getting a `ValueError` exception on the second or third `if` statement.

Comment: Just put continue into the end of each if statement, except the one has break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed your code for you. Try this:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 100)

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input("Guess the number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid number, try again!")
        continue

    if guess < x:
        print("Too low, guess again")

    elif guess > x:
        print("Too high, guess again")

    elif x == guess:
        print ("That is correct!")
        break
```

You don't need to prompt the user for input after every guess, that's what the first input prompt is for. Because we are specifying `while True`, the user will get prompted to input a number every single time unless they enter the correct number, which in that case, we `break` the infinite loop.

Additionally, we can put the input statement in a `try` block, because we are casting the input as an integer right there. If the user enters a string, the program would otherwise fail if it tried to cast it as an integer, but if we `except ValueError:` and then `continue`, we will alert the user that their input is invalid, and then prompt them for input once again.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements are all independent:

```
if x > int(guess):
    print("Too low, guess again")
    guess = input("Guess the number")

if x < int(guess):
    print("Too high, guess again")
    guess = input("Guess the number")

if x == int(guess):
    print ("That is correct!")
    break
```

The second and third `if` statements will *always* test `guess` again, even if the first `if` test matched. And if the first `if` test matched and you entered a non-numeric `guess` value, those two tests will fail as the `int()` call will throw a `ValueError` exception.

You could tell Python that the tests are interdependent by using `elif` and `else`; now Python will only execute the *first matching block*, and skip the others entirely:

```
if x > int(guess):
    print("Too low, guess again")
    guess = input("Guess the number")

elif x < int(guess):
    print("Too high, guess again")
    guess = input("Guess the number")

else:
    print ("That is correct!")
    break
```

This means that execution continuous *after* the `else` block when either the `if` or `elif` tests matched.

Note that I used `else` at the end; if the number is neither too high nor too low, the number *must* be equal, there is no other option. There is no need to test for that explicitly.

You are now repeating yourself however. You are asking for a guess in 3 different places. You could ask *once* and let the loop take care of asking for a new value:

```
while True:
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess the number:")
        if guess.isnumeric():
            break
        print("Not a valid number, try again!")

    guess = int(guess)

    if x > guess:
        print("Too low, guess again")

    elif x < guess:
        print("Too high, guess again")

    else:
        print ("That is correct!")
        break
```

That's a lot less repetition already; a separate `while` loop asks for a number until it is actually numeric, and `guess` is converted to `int()` just once.

You could remove that nested `while True:` and just use the outer one here, the result would be the same, provided you use the `continue` keyword to skip the rest of the loop when you don't have a numeric value:

```
while True:
    guess = input("Guess the number:")
    if not guess.isnumeric():
        print("Not a valid number, try again!")
        continue  # skip to the top of the loop again, so ask again

    guess = int(guess)

    if x > guess:
        print("Too low, guess again")

    elif x < guess:
        print("Too high, guess again")

    else:
        print ("That is correct!")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your guessing logic in another loop that continues until the guess is correct.

pseudocode:

```
choose_target_answer
while player_has_not_guessed_answer
    get_player_guess
    if player_guess_is_valid
        respond_to_player_guess
    else
        give_error_message
```